# How to make hybrid app for open browser. phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, windows-phone

I want to make a hybrid app for open a website on system browser, 
After my splashscreen will redirect for browser, then close the application.
I need automatic redirect.
And i cant open that on browser inside phonegap cause that restric some thinks as i need.
How i supose do that?
I was looking for and just found for open a link, or button or some like that.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, just a eventListener, when device start.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://www.google.com.br/', '_system', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }
    </script>
```